# Jest tests run multiple times, once for every React class imported

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

My jest tests are running multiple time and giving bad results. Experiment shows that each component imported causes the tests to run again.

```
const App = require("./App.js");
const Check = require("./view/newOrder/Check.js");

it("doesn't work at all", (done) => {
  console.log("This should only print once");
  done();
});
```

prints

```
This should only print once 
This should only print once
```

Comment: Why you are calling done inside? First argument of it is Test Description and Second argument is a function which is going to run and checks for the expectations. I don't think manually you have to call this.

Comment: Jest isn't tied to imports this way and cannot do the thing you describe. It's not evident that *each component imported causes the tests to run again*. It's likely that you run in Jest watch mode and something retriggers test run. Try to disable it https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--watchall . In case the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce it.